# Sendgrid not rendering AMP email

Tags: laravel, sendgrid, amp-html, amp-email

I have set up an AMP email in Laravel and using Sendgrid as a mail driver.

Below is mailable:

```
public function build()
    {

        $amp = View::make('emails.amp.test');

        $this->view('emails.amp.test')
            ->subject('Amp test')
            ->from("notifications@myapp1234.com", 'MyApp');

        return $this->withSwiftMessage(function (\Swift_Message $message) use ($amp) {
            $message->addPart($amp->render(), 'text/x-amp-html', 'utf-8');
        });

    }
```

Below is the view (emails.amp.test):

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html ⚡4email>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    
        <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
        <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    
        <style amp4email-boilerplate>
        body {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <style amp-custom>
table {
            background: rgb(241, 244, 247) none repeat;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 30px 100px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            color: rgb(10, 8, 58);
            max-width: 800px;
        }
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><amp-img
                      alt="A view of the sea"
                      src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014__340.jpg"
                      width="900"
                      height="675"
                      layout="responsive"
                    >
                    </amp-img></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have also enabled Dynamic Email as well as whitelisted From address in Gmail settings. Authenticated the domain in Sendgrid. The sender address SPF and DKIM passed.

But when I send an email, it shows like this in Gmail.

[image]

I am not even able to debug it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with the emoji in the HTML? Also, the `view` method is to add an HTML component to the email. It looks like you're just adding the same information twice to the email, once with a `text/html` MIME type and once with `text/x-amp-html`.

Comment: I'm sure you have referred this document

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/google-amp-for-email

Comment: What portion of the HTML _does_ render in Gmail? Any of it?